# How to find the sum of elements in nested list?

Tags: python, sum, nested-lists

Below is the given list:

```
x = [[50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60]]
```

What I need here is the sum of numbers of each nested list in a different list.

For e.g `[162,163,.....]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just loop through the items.

First you loop through the internal lists:

```
for lst in x:
```

Then you sum the items in the list using the `sum` method:
    total = sum(lst)

Together it looks like this:

```
new_list = list()
for lst in x:
    lst = sum(lst)
    new_list.append(total)

print(new_list)
```

Hope this helps.

*Edit: I haven't used the sum method before. Which is why the two downvotes despite the program working fine.*

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = [[50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60]]
>>> y = [sum(i) for i in x]
>>> y
[162, 163, 165, 165, 167, 168, 170, 172, 173, 175]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do :

```
x = [[50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60]]

print(list(map(sum,x)))
```

output:

```
[162, 163, 165, 165, 167, 168, 170, 172, 173, 175]
```

Comment: Why the `lambda`?  Why not simply `print(list(map(sum, x)))`.  Adding the `lambda` seems to just complicate the expression and slow it down.